# Zoom Bot to get Participants List as Participant

Tags: python, automation, zoom-sdk

I need the get the list of participants in a currently running zoom meeting. Should be pretty easy with the Zoom API, right? Well ...

1. I'm not the host/cohost.
2. I have a basic zoom membership.

I need this for my school. A group of 3 students (we call them captains) have to report to the Head Teacher about the attendance status of our class. As a programmer, I'm thinking of ways to automate the process (maybe using python or something similar?)

I'm not sure if this is illegal to do, if so please let me know and I'll ditch the idea. Otherwise some ideas to implement this would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Abhigyan: Go through Zoom's API documentation and coming to the sad realisation that I need to have a Business plan or above to use their API, and I also need to be a host/cohost :(

Comment: Ok, but where is your code?

Comment: I haven't written any code yet. I'm looking for a way to code it :)

Comment: If you have ipen computer you can try automation..

Comment: can you provide resources on `ipen computers`? I couldn't find anything on google